# RandomAccessSubList not serialized

Tags: java, list

I am trying to get a sublist of a `List` but I want the sublist to be serialized. I found out that when we get sublist from an `ArrayList` the sublist is not serialized.

To overcome this, this is what I am doing:

```
ArrayList serializedSublist = new ArrayList();
//getQuestions() returns RandomAccessSubList
getQuestions().addAll(serializedSublist); 
//problem is in the line below. serializedSublist is empty.
getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("questionsForUser", serializedSublist);
```

Problem is that `serializedSubList` is empty in line 5, eventhough in line 3 `getQuestions()` returns a list back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're adding it backwards, no? Shouldn't it be

```
serializedSublist.addAll(getQuestions());
```

or, better, yet

```
ArrayList serializedSublist = new ArrayList(getQuestions());
```

Comment: To expand the excellent answer: here's what API says about `addAll()`: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29 In the future keep in mind to consult the API docs first. They contains answers on this kind of questions/problems about Java behaviour.