# Why is java.util.RandomAccessSubList not serializable?

Tags: java, serialization

Yesterday I had an odd exception that a class cannot be cast to itself - which took me several headbanging hours to solve.

Long story short, the reason turned out to be that my EJB service returns a RandomAccessSubList for some cases, which (after checking the source out) I noticed was not Serializable.

Of course I realize the guys who created this are probably much smarter than me but I couldn't help thinking that this is not a particularly good design decision.

I understand that not all List implementations are Serializable, but why doesn't then the subList method take care of this by providing a SubList instance which implements Serializable for parents that also implement Serializable? It certainly does provide this for the RandomAccess interface.

Or why not just mark the RandomAccessSubList as Serializable and let the original implementation (which RandomAccessSubList has a reference to) worry about the Serialization?

Comment: Let's say you have a list with 1 million elements, take a sublist of 10 elements, and serialize it the way you suggest. that would still serialize 1 million elements, which is probably not what you want an expect. So, if you want a copy, explicitely create it using `new ArrayList<>(subList)`

Comment: Some insight on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883049/randomaccesssublist-not-serialized

Comment: @JBNizet: You're obviously right, but imagine you want to serialize a 1 million of such sublists of the same `List`. Making a copy means using much more memory. I surely agree that your example is more common than mine, but `RandomAccessSubList` not being `Serializable` helps to prevent a mistake in one case and causes big problems in the other.